# Validation error rendering same page but not retaining the data added in rhomobile

Tags: validation, render, rhomobile

I have implemented model validations, but when rendering back the new action, it is not retaining the data entered.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have implemented validation in model and the data which you are entering is not saved in the database,so how it can retain the data entered.

Comment: Try to insert the data which is valid by your validation.And your question is also not self explanatory please try to add screen-sorts.